# internal error: unable to execute QEMU command 'cont': Resetting the Virtual Machine is required

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, virsh

I try to install a kvm img in my vps, but after i install it, it show

```
root@wz:~# virsh list
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
 12    guaji                          paused
```

and i run

```
root@wz:~# virsh resume guaji
error: Failed to resume domain guaji
error: internal error: unable to execute QEMU command 'cont': Resetting the Virtual Machine is required
```

i try to reproduce it in vagrant with same kernel(ubuntu 14.04 lts), but it work well

**my question is:** how to fix it?

**update** i try `tail -n 1000 /var/log/libvirt/qemu/guaji-clone.log' and get:

```
char device redirected to /dev/pts/1 (label charserial0)
KVM: entry failed, hardware error 0x0
EAX=00000000 EBX=00000000 ECX=00000000 EDX=00000663
ESI=00000000 EDI=00000000 EBP=00000000 ESP=00000000
EIP=0000e05b EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00009300
CS =f000 000f0000 0000ffff 00009b00
SS =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00009300
DS =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00009300
FS =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00009300
GS =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00009300
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00
GDT=     00000000 0000ffff
IDT=     00000000 0000ffff
CR0=60000010 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
EFER=0000000000000000
Code=85 00 87 00 89 00 8b 00 00 00 86 00 88 00 8a 00 8c 00 00 90 <2e> 66 83 3e a4 65 00 0f 85 53 f2 31 c0 8e d0 66 bc 00 70 00 00 66 ba 4f 3c 0f 00 e9 b1 f0
(reverse-i-search)`tl': tl /var/log/libvirt/qemu/guaji-clone.log
```

Comment: Please describe fully the host system which is having the problem. Hardware, Linux distribution version, kernel, and anything else that may be interesting or unusual about it.

Answer (score 1):

`virsh destroy guaji`

`virsh start guaji`

This should get the VM up if there are no configuration or hardware problems

Comment: I doesn't work, i only reproduce this bug on digitalocean ubuntu14.04, i think it's there hardward problem

Answer (score 0):

In my Ubuntu 16.04 ppc64el system, disabling SMT has fixed it:

```
sudo ppc64_cpu --smt=off
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same error once when I changed os->loader->type from pflash to from in order to enable snapshots.
I did it within Virt-Manager XML viewer and I don't know why, but the value changed from `/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE.fd` to `usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE.ms.fd`.

I just undid this change and my VM was booting again. So one should double-check XML definitions.

Answer (score -1):

I migrate my app from digitalocean to linode, very thing work well, I think the reason is digitaloccean close "intel vt" in its server.